# Multiple crosshair

Tags: highcharts

We are evaluating the highcharts JS library. We need:

- to display in the same graph, up to 10 line series of 256 000 points each: OK
- to display annotations: OK
- to be able to set 2 X-crosshair to be able to display, inside a tooltip or a specific zone, the differences/delta in X and Y betwwen the both crossair. Is it possible to acheive that?

Best regards,
Xavier

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like is done here: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/stock-tools-gui ? Please check how the `measure` works - it is a 5th label from the top.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian for you quick answer.

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for. This demo is quick more complex beacuse it acts also in Y axis by taking into account also the value in Y. I need only to get deltas between X (distance in meters) and Y (measured value). I throwed an eye on code in Jsfiddle and this feature seems to be part of your stock-tool librairy ?

Comment: yes, it is a part of a stock-tools module. Do you have some pictures of your requirement? Is this crosshair should be set dynamically? Maybe a using the plotLines feature will be a better approach? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines and show data in label?

Comment: It is something like that with 2 plotLines that can be dragged (with the ability to stick to points).

Comment: How can I send you a photo?

Answer (score 0):

It is a really custom functionality. It could be achieved by creating the initials plotLines and by implementing the possibility to drag them. I tried to explain everything by the comments in the demo.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/efL6wyjr/

The initial plotLines:

```
  xAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
      value: 2,
      width: 4,
      color: 'red',
    }, {
      value: 5,
      width: 4,
      color: 'red'
    }]
  },
```

If something is unclear - feel free to ask.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toValue

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

Comment: It is clear. Thanks. Is it possible to activate this feature (display both plotLines) in the "export" menu?

Comment: When establishing the text label,  how can you have access to Y value of series? Especially if you are between 2 points (interpolation).

Comment: Here is a demo shows how to render those plotLines for the exporting: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vcbaq6Lj/

Comment: Something like this? Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xgt4ovdm/ Feel free to simplified the shared code.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. In fact I wanted to activate this feature not during export. I wanted a way to activate the feature by this way. At the very beginning, there is no plotLines but when clicking on a new item of the menu (created for this purpose), both plotLines appear. Whene clicking again on this item of the menu, both plotLines disappear.

Comment: Thanks for your last demo. I understood how to have access to values of the series. Now I see how we can get the Y values associated to each plotLine (values where each plotLine meet the serie).

Comment: Do you think, this solution can be effective in case of series of 256.000 points? Because we need to browse all the series' points to find the right X position. It is time consuming and we also need to handle the zooming/panning case.

Comment: @XavierBouchery toggling plotLines from export menu: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jxvf3dna/ - This code is written in the simple, not complicate way for your better understanding, many of functions are similar or even repeated - you can easily improve it for your needs.  I am not sure how the performance will be for series with 256k points, but it should work. May I see a basic demo with a sample of your data to test?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious answers. It helps a lot. We are trying to implement this in a small mockup (but with with Wildfly and Angular 8). I am not sure we can easily share. Let me see (more difficult with lockdown and teleworking in France).

Comment: @XavierBouchery It might be a dummy data. Here is a template which you can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-go8sk

Comment: We are preparing a sample of 250k points inside this environment to be able to test it and to share a common and realistic graph.

Comment: We prepared the sample and tried to test it inside CodeSandbox but teh result is very slow. Is there any solution to share this project with you? Or any solution to provide you the data?

Comment: @XavierBouchery we can try through the CodeSandbox.You need to save and fork your demo and share the link with me.

Comment: I forked the project https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-vcdm5. I created the file data.csv containing data in csv (; as delimiter). I was looking for how to read the file. May be you can help me.

Comment: I am afraid that such a big amount of data must be rendered using the boost module. API: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x308vwqk/ and the demo with my attempt to render plotLines: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fd158b6g/

Comment: I think so too. However your code seems to be compatible with the boost module. What could be the best way/format to inject this amount of data (10MB of json)?

Comment: If it is impossible to recreate data to a smaller format (deleting unnecessary code etc) I think that you can use the Highcharts loading to show the loading screen while fetching data. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/loading Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hLj1advd/